# Getting started with [Wrap]Bootstrap theme with Bower/Grunt

Tags: html, angularjs, npm, gruntjs, bower

This is my first attempt at using a frontend package that uses Grunt/Bower.
I am specifically referring to a Wrapbootstrap theme.

I followed the instructions as follows:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install -g bower
npm install
bower install
```

I believe the process went fine. There were some deprecation warnings though.

What I ended up was with a file structure like this:

[image]

However, now I am lost as how to start.
The instructions says to do `grunt live` but it just opens up a blank page without anything on it. I opened every index.html in there but no luck.

Would really appreciate if you someone can set me on a path to realizing how to deal with the Grunt/Bower tools and how to troubleshoot this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Where did you get the commands to run? Can you provide the link of the tutorial or documentation?

Comment: @muecas thank you very much. Not sure if I link here, but this is the theme I got: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/luna-responsive-admin-theme-WB0J69TPB I executed those commands in the root folder, where package.json and bower.json are in.

Comment: The purchase website does not provide the installation options. I recommend you to read the provided documentation. Or if you need some help with it, add the documentation or “read me” file to your question.